# Is it possible to specify the function type using ->

Tags: java

I have following method definition, which works.

```
public static String runFunction2(Function<String,String> function, String input) {
    return function.apply(input);
}
```

But I want to specify the function type explicitly like Scala does:

```
public static String runFunction(String -> String function, String input) {
    return function.apply(input);
}
```

There is compiling error in the above code, Does Java 8 not support this snytax?

Comment: Nope it doesn't.

Comment: Lambda looks a tad different, which may be the closest to the syntax you'd be looking for.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you forgot the return types, what is the difference between your first example and second example?  One is Java syntax and one is Scala syntax, but they do the same thing.  They both "specify the function type explicitly".  What do you want the Java example to do differently?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong - I read the Question as asking if it is possible to use Scala-like syntax in Java.  The answer is "No you can't".

Comment: @StephenC Ok, I think I see now.  Just an odd question.  I mean, you can't use Scala syntax in C either, but I wouldn't post a question about it, I would think that would be obvious...  I guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Java doesn't support that syntax.  In fact, Java doesn't have any special syntax for function types<sup>1</sup>.

Java function types are a kind of Java interface type, and you need to use the same syntax that you use when using any interface type.

Java only has special syntax (for example lambdas and method references) for expressing function *values*.

---

<sup>1 - It is not impossible that a future Java version might, but I wouldn't hold my breath waiting ...</sup>